# Largest array / Comparing arrays (fresh view?)

Tags: java, arrays

Could someone watch it with a fresh view? I can't find my mistake.

Exercise and example:

```
Input:
4 4
1 4 5 7
10 4 6 8
```

First two numbers: 1) amount of products 2) amount of customers. Next line: prices of products. Third line: amount of money customers have.
**Script has to recommend the most expensive product for customers in their range of money.** Inputs are different each time

```
Output:
7 4 5 7
```

I'm having a problem with that part of the code:

```
int largest = price[0];

for(int i = 1; i < money.length; i++) {
    for(int a = 1; a < price.length; a++) {
        if(price[a] > largest && largest <= money[i]) {
            largest = price[a];
            System.out.print(largest + " ");
        }
    } 
}
```

Full code if necessary

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String[] sizes = scan.nextLine().split(" ");
        int[] price = new int[Integer.parseInt(sizes[0])];
        int[] money = new int[Integer.parseInt(sizes[1])];

        String[] inputprice = scan.nextLine().split(" ");
        for (int i = 0; i < price.length; i++) {
            price[i] = Integer.parseInt(inputprice[i]);
        }

        String[] inputmoney = scan.nextLine().split(" ");
        for (int i = 0; i < money.length; i++) {
            money[i] = Integer.parseInt(inputmoney[i]);
        }
        scan.close();

        int largest = price[0];
        for (int i = 1; i < money.length; i++) {
            for (int a = 1; a < price.length; a++) {
                if (price[a] > largest && largest <= money[i]) {
                    largest = price[a];
                    System.out.print(largest + " ");
                }
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

Edit:
Still gives bit wrong answer, but there has been an improvement:

```
for(int i = 0; i < money.length; i++) {
      int largest = price[0];
      for(int a = 0; a < price.length; a++){
        if(price[a] > largest && largest <= money[i]){
          largest = price[a];
        }
      }
      System.out.print(largest+ " ");
    }
```

Gives answer:

```
Output:
7 4 7 7
```

Edit:
**Code seems to work but throws runtime error while posting it into codeforce. How so?**

Comment: The arrays are zero based, and you're initializing the for loops from 1. Also, you'll need to initialize `largest` for each run of the outer for loop.

Comment: What error you are getting

Comment: With my code i got output: "4 5 7", but didn't get the first answer. With @Nimrod Argov's solution, getting " 4 5 7 4 5 4 5 7 4 5 7 " as an answer

Comment: You're also printing every time you find a larger number. Print after the inner loop ends.

Comment: Gives "7 5 7 7 " as an answer :/

Comment: @waynekenoff. This condition is wrong `if(price[a] > largest && largest <= money[i])`. It should be `if (price[a] > largest && price[a] <= money[i])`.

Comment: Thank you guys :) It seems to work. Has anyone also have an idea how to fix runtime error? Throws runtime error in codeforce :/

Comment: The ```int largest = price[0];``` initialization assumes that everyone can buy the cheapest product, which is not necessarily the case. You could start from ```int largest=-1;```. Also, right now you are storing only the price of the viable product, but you should also store its index.

Comment: @tevemadar if I understand your comment correctly then the answer is that after something is bought, others can still buy it. I think thats the answer for your question? If not, correct me. My brain isn't as functionable as it should be xD

Comment: What I mean is if you use input ```4 4```, ```1 4 5 7```, ```0 4 6 8```, it will still suggest 1 for the first customer. It suggests the cheapest product to people who can not actually buy it - it is either okay or not, you decide.

Comment: Oh yes, thanks, that i'll try to fix. Has anyone also have an idea how i could fix that runtime error? :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two mistakes in your latest version:

- The initialization `int largest = price[0];` is not correct. You should initialize to the lowest possible value, otherwise `largest` may be invalid (incorrectly too high). You could set it to `Integer.MIN_VALUE`.
- The condition `price[a] > largest && largest <= money[i]` is incorrect, it should be `price[a] > largest && price[a] <= money[i]`

Also, it would be better to use a for-each loop:

```
for (int m : money) {
    int largest = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    for (int p : price) {
        if (p > largest && p <= m) {
            largest = p;
        }
    }
    System.out.print(largest + " ");
}
```

Note that the performance of this algorithm is `O(m * p)`,
where `m` is the length of `money` and `p` is the length of `price`.
You could make it `O(p log p) + O(m * log p)` by sorting `price` and using binary search to find the highest price.