# Removing space " " after last element

Tags: java, arrays, space

Extension to: [Largest array / Comparing arrays (fresh view?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47619793/largest-array-comparing-arrays-fresh-view)

Could someone give me a hint/solution how could I change code, so after the last output number it wouldn't add space after it?

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
   Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
 int[] productsAndCustomers = Arrays.stream(in.nextLine().split(" ")).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).toArray();
 int[] hind = Arrays.stream(in.nextLine().split(" ")).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).toArray(); 
 int[] raha = Arrays.stream(in.nextLine().split(" ")).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).toArray();

    for (int m : raha) {
        int largest = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        for (int p : hind) {
            if (p > largest && p <= m) {
                largest = p;
            }
        }
        System.out.print(largest + " ");
    }
  }
}
```

Although it shows the right answer, It has to be that it won't show that spacing after that last output number. What would be the best option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a variable space and initialize it with a space after the first iteration like this :

```
String space = "";
for (int m : raha) {
    //Your code...
    System.out.print(space + largest);
    space = " ";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Good idea is to use `StringBuilder` - you could use method `append()` to add all `largest` and after the for loop you could use its `delete()` method to get rid of last character.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest just using a regular, not an enhanced `for` loop so you can know when you are checking the `raha` array's last element.

Try:

```
for(int i = 0; i < raha.length; i++) {
    // Your code
    if(raha[i] != raha.length - 1)
        System.out.println(largest + " ");
    else
        System.out.println(largest);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Java 8, then there's a simple method: instead of printing the results right away, you can collect them into a collection, and then use `String.join` method:

```
List<String> results = new ArrayList<>();
for (int m : raha) {
    int largest = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    for (int p : hind) {
        if (p > largest && p <= m) {
            largest = p;
        }
    }
    results.add(Integer.toString(largest));
}
System.out.println(String.join(" ", results));
```

If you're not using Java 8, then you will have to use some third party library that provides a similar `join` method.

If you don't want to collect the results, then you will have to track the index (so use a regular for loop instead of outer foreach) and omit the space for the last index.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over array with for loop and implement simple if check to see if current iteration is last one:

```
if (i == array.length - 1)
    System.out.print(element);
else
    System.out.print(element + " ");
```

There are many more different ways, this is one of the easiest I can remember.